# Particles they fly over the mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, edit-mode

I have an uneven shape and on it I would like to "plant" the grass, but it comes out so that one grass flew in the air and the other grows well.

I would like to get the effect of growing from mesh grass.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, flew in the air?

Comment: they do not grow out of the ground

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing your blend file.  One question I would have is whether the origins of the objects in your dupli group are in the right locations (i.e., at or near the base of each grass strand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because your using a group. If you make each different grass blade an individual object and gave each of them a different particle system, you may avoid grass that floats in the air.

Comment: I set 2 in Velocity emiter object Z